# Security problem With file generated by Firebase “com.google.InstanceId.properties” file?

Tags: android, firebase, security

I'm testing the security of my Android application and discovered that Firebase generates a `com.google.InstanceId.properties` file, which contains private and public `RSA` keys.

My question is:

- is there any risk for my Firebase?
- is it possible to force Firebase to save this file in secure storage?